# .htaccess rewrite with / at the end

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I've got the follow code in my.htaccess

```
 Options +FollowSymlinks
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^([\w\d~%.:_\-]+)$ category.php?id=$1 [NC]
```

Which changes the url: www.domain.com/category.php?id=uncategorized

to

www.domain.com/uncategorized

However when I go to http://www.domain.com/uncategorized/ with a slash at the end, it says the page does not exists. Does anyone know how I can make it so that the new URL will work regardless if it ends with a slash or not, and everything else like that?

Answer (score 0):

You can make trailing slash optional and add `QSA` flag:

```
 Options +FollowSymlinks
 RewriteEngine on

 # add a trailing slash
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?)[^/][?\s]
 RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^([\w\d~%.:-]+)/?$ category.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: This is great! Is there a way to make it always end with a slash? Perhaps redirecting the URL to always with a slash?

Comment: There seems to be a problem. Now all my links, images and CSS files have the filename them. For example, if I go to domain.com/category all my links will be like domain.com/category/index.php when it should be domain.com/index.php. In other words, I think the filename has been added into the base URL of every link.

Comment: No where in these rules I am adding `index.php` in URI so I am sure that is happening outside these rules. If you comment out trailing slash rule does it work fine?

Comment: No no, you're not adding index.php. But if I have a link that is index.php somewhere in the page as a html link, it will add the filename to it. So if I go to domain.com/filename the index.php link on the page will become /filename/index.php. So if I click on the index.php it will take me to /filename/index.php which is wrong.

Comment: That is because you are using relative URLs. Just use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

Answer (score 0):

This will redirect urls without a slash at the end to a url with a slash at the end.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*[^/]$ /$0/ [L,R=301]
```